# why does git give me a CONFLICT error when merging a branch that performed a rename?

Tags: git, merge

I have 2 branches in git

- `master`
- `breaking_changes`

On the `breaking_changes` branch I renamed a file from `user/term_+_bash.sh` to `dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh`
I also performed the same rename action (renamed the same file and gave it the same name), but independently on the `master` branch.
I then tried to merge in the work from the master branch and I got this

```
$ git merge master 
CONFLICT (rename/delete): dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh deleted in HEAD and renamed in master.  
Version master of dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

`git status` gives

```
$ git status
On branch breaking_changes

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        added by them:      dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Im not sure what has happened, How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh` and fix the conflicts. Then run

```
$ git add dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh
```

Then run

```
git commit -m "your-message"
```

Comment: thanks, so are you saying, I need to open the file `dev/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh` make any changes necessary to resolve, then just `add ` and `commit` and thats it?

Comment: yes, from your status, it just looks like simple merge conflict